# Media queries as replacement for code regions?

Tags: css, media-queries

I thought it would be a neat idea to put my *default* css which has no width/height/.. dependencies in a media query like this:

```
@media only all and (min-width: 0px){ ... }
```

Are there any possible drawbacks I've missed?

Comment: What benefit do you see in doing so?

Comment: @Leo more organized *code*. I generally love code regions as in [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9a1ybwek.aspx). Also I don't like to use CSS compilers . And for known reasons I want to keep my css in one file (at least css that belongs together)

Comment: But isn't it the same as just putting that CSS code before all media queries?

Comment: @Leo no. Not in sense of readability - when you use an IDE / text-editor that supports collapsing.

Comment: Better still, use sass / less and place the default styles in a partial. This seems like a hack for the sake of being able to minimise / expand your code blocks.

Comment: I agree using a CSS compiler like SASS is the way to go if you want to better organize your styles...

Comment: is there a plugin / IDE that will add code blocks based on code comment patterns? This functionality might be a happy medium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as readable to be honest with you. If I were to see that in a CSS file, I would assume it's some weird CSS hack.

The other downside is you're adding an unnecessary media query. Setting all your default attributes through a media query is making more work for the CSS compiler.

Finally is support. Not all browsers support media queries, especially if you work in enterprise or with clients who have very old browsers. If you have all your defaults set through media queries you don't have an easy fallback if those queries fail.

Comment: None of these arguments apply to my situation. Anyway, these are reasonable arguments and I guess it would be a bad habit to do it. Thanks for your answer, I'll keep the question open for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use anything that isn't really adding to your webpages.

The unnecessary use of media queries can also cause problems with old browsers (eg. IE 7,8,9) if there is no polyfilling. It will also add to the page load time.

There are other numerous ways to increase readablity:

1.opening and closing comment lines to a set of CSS blocks

```
/******default code******/
html{
..... 
}

body{
.....
}
/****--default code--****/
```

2. separate CSS files
3. code collapsing in IDE

other tips are mentioned here at [Improving Code Readability With CSS Styleguides](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/02/improving-code-readability-with-css-styleguides/)

Comment: 1. It's still annoying (imho) when you have many collapsed lines 2. would almost force me to use a compiler - I would like to avoid that 3. same as 1

Comment: one wouldn't give you any collapsed lines